# Mapping two arrays - from a talk with my Holand teacher

Tags: php, set

I am going to have a nice small talk with my teacher from Netherlands tonight via skype :-D
I am guessing this might be what he will ask me to explain.

I have two arrays, `X` and its child `XX`

```
X = {"item1","item2","item3"}
XX= {"item11","item12"};
```

for example.

These two `X` and `XX` data are read from the same database table therefore I know their ids (auto_increment)

```
X's id is 100 and each of its element also has an id (e.g 10,11,12)
XX's id is 101 and each of its element also has an id(e.g 13,14,15)
```

Also `X` and `XX` also have their parent ids (e.g `200` and `100` respectively). You see this `id=100` of `XX` points to its parent `X`. And each of the elements of `XX` has the same parent that is `item1` whose `id` is `10`.

However, the parent doesn't have any "flag" to tell me that it does have some children. The problem occurs.

```
foreach($X as $x)
{
   foreach($XX as $xx)
   {
      if($xx->parentId==$x->id)
      {
         echo "Ahha children know they have their parents";
      }       
   }
}
```

Yes, that code piece runs fine but by all means I would love to look into some way to echo "Ahha Parents now know parents also have some children". Thank you.

Comment: Could you, just to clarify, post a `print_r` of `$X` and `$XX`?

Comment: With or without transforming the "model"? I.e. can you change the way the information is stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my question, I'm not 100% sure about your question, but this might be the way to solve your problem:

```
foreach($X as $x)
{
    foreach($XX as $xx)
    {
        if ($xx->parentId == $x->id)
        {
            echo "Ahha children know they have their parents";
            if (!isset($x->children)) {
                $x->children = array();
            }
            $x->children[] = $xx;
        }
    }
    if (!empty($x->children)) {
        echo "This parent has " . count($x->children) . " children";
    }
}
```